# How do you enable button if one of the input field is already prepopulated?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

To clarify this question. I have two inputs fields, sometimes one of the input field is already pre-populated based on if its user or guest. If guest both are empty, enter text on both input the button will be enabled. However if user, one of the input field is already populated with its said name, but the button is still disabled when I entered some text on the other field. It seems like the pre-populated input field is still consider empty even if there's already value inside of it. How do you fix this situation?

```
  const [confirmNumber, setConfirmNumber] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [validNumber, setValidNumber] = useState(true);
  const [validName, setValidName] = useState(true);
  const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

  const confirmNumberHandler = (val: string) => {
    setConfirmNumber(val);
    setValidNumber(true);
  };

  const lastNameHandler = (val: string) => {
    setLastName(val);
    setValidName(true);
  };
```

```
const buttonDisable = () => {
    if (confirmNumber !== '' && lastName !== '') {
      return false; //the bottom if statement doesn't seem to work :( any other solutions?
    } else if (confirmNumber !== '' && lastName === name) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
```

```
        <InputField
          autoFocus
          onChangeText={confirmNumberHandler}
          error={!validNumber}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.viewMargin}>
        <InputField
// I haven't created any condition for this value this is a just a hard coded string. to test if there's value already there.
          value={name}
          onChangeText={lastNameHandler}
          error={!validName}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
        <PrimaryButton
          showLoading={loading}
          disabled={buttonDisable()}
          onPress={() => {
            lookUpHandler();
          }}>
        </PrimaryButton>
```

Comment: could you paste the whole code of the component, with all the handlers?

Comment: @lanxion I had pasted the whole handlers component.

Comment: @lanxion let me know if you need any other informations. I am still currently still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `name` into the `value` prop of `InputField` as you can see from this snippet of your provided code.

```js
<InputField
  value={name}
  onChangeText={lastNameHandler}
  error={!validName}
/>
```

But `name` is not a state in your component, but `lastName` which you are using to check the conditions as well as the state you are setting in `onChangeText`, thus you need to assign the state that you want the `value` prop of your `InputField` to store the text in to be a state in your component.

To say it in other words: you're `InputField` never stores the actual value in the correct state.

You can fix this as follows.

```js
<InputField
  value={lastName}
  onChangeText={lastNameHandler}
  error={!validName}
/>
```

For providing an initial value to your `InputField`, you need to pass them as a prop to your component as follows.

```js
const MyForm = ({initalName}) => {

    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(initialName);
}
```

In the parent container you pass the intial value into the component. This could look as follows.

```js
const MainScreen = () => }


   return (
        <MyForm initialName={"Max"} />
   )
}
```

If your form does handle this on its own using some API call, then you could do this initially in a `useEffect` on first render.

```js
const MyForm = () => {

    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        someApiCallForLastName().then(response => setLastName(response.lastName))
    }, [setLastName])
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to use the Api call for the last name. But 'then' keeps coming up as an error that said does not exist on type 'string'. useEffect(() => {
    trips.upcomingReservations[0].loyaltyProfile?.lastName.then((response: any) => setLastName(response.lastName));
  }, [setLastName]);    (P.S. I have been using typescript)

Comment: Then your api call does not return a promise. Just use `setLastName(trips.upcomingReservations[0].loyaltyProfile?.lastName)`

Comment: nope now the whole line inside the parameter is an error ;(. Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'.

Comment: This is an typescript error. Your code should work nevertheless. In order to fix the typescript error just type it... `useState<string | undefined>()`;

Comment: now it says undefined is not an object. (evaluating trips.upcomingReservation[0].loyaltyProfile') lolol >.<

Comment: Then either `trips` or `upcomingReservations` is undefined ... You haven't shared your whole code. It is hard to say what is going on. If some of the accessed properties are undefined, then of course it is not working, but this is a problem with your data.

Comment: I think it has to do with the data. I am just going to use a local json data that's a lot easier to read and edit. since the api I was using have multiple plus multiple different datas.

Comment: Try that and let me know if it works :) If not I'm happy to help.

Comment: I tried it with a different Data and it works! Thank you!!

Comment: That is great to hear! :) Good luck with further coding.